# DestinationInvalid on CopyIntoItems Copy webservice

Tags: sharepoint-server, soap

When I'm uploading a file to SharePoint 2010 using soap webservice, I'm getting a Error Code like

> Destination Invalid

My Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<soap:CopyIntoItems>         <soap:SourceUrl>C:\Users\system30\Desktop\icons\employee.jpg</soap:SourceUrl>
<soap:DestinationUrls>
<soap:string>http://192.168.20.123:80/Shared Documents/employee.jpg</soap:string>
</soap:DestinationUrls>
<soap:Fields>
<soap:FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Description" InternalName="Description" Value="sample"/>
</soap:Fields>
<soap:Stream>here my endoded string(base64)</soap:Stream>
</soap:CopyIntoItems>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I'm getting the following error code when executing

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CopyIntoItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>
<Results>
<CopyResult ErrorCode="DestinationInvalid" ErrorMessage="The Copy web service method must be called on the same domain that contains the destination url." DestinationUrl="http://192.168.20.123:80/Shared Documents/employee.png"/>
</Results>
</CopyIntoItemsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And permission for my site is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEl7T.png)

Answer (score 1):

plz find below code snippet it will help you to get resolve you file uploading issue

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://sp:2000/sites/ex1/Style%20Library/JSFiles/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function uploadFile() {

    var filePath = "‪C:\\Users\sp_admin\Desktop\MYDOC.docx";
    //I have alredy Create Doc on below path for testing  purposer
    **var url= "http://sp:2000/sites/ex1/TestDocUplode/MYDOC.docx";**

    var soapEnv =
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soap:Body>\
            <CopyIntoItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>\
                <SourceUrl>" + filePath + "</SourceUrl>\
                    <DestinationUrls>\
                        <string> "+ url + "</string>\
                    </DestinationUrls>\
                    <Fields>\
                        <FieldInformation Type='Text' DisplayName='Title' InternalName='Title' Value='Test' />\
                    </Fields>\
                <Stream>base64Binary</Stream>\
            </CopyIntoItems>\
        </soap:Body>\
    </soap:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://sp:2000/sites/ex1/_vti_bin/copy.asmx",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems"); },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
    alert(soapEnv);
}
function processResult(xData, status) {
    alert("Uploaded SuccessFully");
}
 </script>
<input name="Upload" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()" type="button"/>
```